# Do I cover a fermenting a bread starter

Tags: bread

do I need to cover the jar that the fermenting bread starter is in?
If so, cover with what?

Answer (score 2):

You want easy airflow, but you don't want dust or bugs. Cheesecloth held on by a rubber band would be perfect.

If you have a container especially for this purpose, and it has a lid, punch or drill a bunch of small holes in it. This is mine:

[image: 1]